# What is the default location of the MediaWiki extensions directory?

Tags: ubuntu, wiki, mediawiki

I recently install MediaWiki on Ubuntu 10.04 using all the default settings. I'm looking to install an extension. Where is the *extensions directory* located by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **locate** (or **find**) to find files or folders, like this:

locate -i mediawiki | grep -i extensions | less

- The **-i**'s mean "ignore case"
- The | (vertical bar) sends the output from one command to the next command as input.
- **grep** is a search tool
- **less** is like the old DOS "more" command on steroids (it allows page up/down and searching)

Comment: I feel pain... `find mediawiki -iname extensions`.

Answer (score 2):

I found my installation folder at `/var/lib/mediawiki/extension`. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 server.

Comment: this only works if you install mediawiki by using "sudo apt-get install" method. If you download tar ball or using svn method (not using ubuntu repository installation), the installation directory will be different and it will probably be at /var/www/mediawiki directory

Answer (score 1):

The `extensions` directory is located under the `mediawiki` directory which is located under `/var/www` by default.